# Inconsistent behavior of inline-block elements when created via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bunch of the same `div`s whose `display` property is set to `inline-block`. I know that `inline-block` elements have, by default, some margin around them so without any modification, I would expect some free space surrounding these elements (this question is not about removing them).

If I simply hard-code them into html file, then they behave as I expect them to.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="1" class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
```

But if I start adding them via JavaScript, the top and bottom margins stays the same, but left and right seems to disappear.

In this code, if I tab into the first element and then hit enter, the new `div` is created and added into `DOM` but as mentioned above, margins are gone when I start adding more of them (hitting enter multiple times).

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('div.box');

btn.addEventListener('keypress', event => {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    const box = document.createElement('div');
    box.className = 'box';
    document.body.appendChild(box);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="1" class='box'></div>
```

Anyone knows why there is a difference in how these `div`s are rendered when hard-coded vs added programmatically? Is there something wrong with the JavaScript code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're confusing white space with margins. Inline elements are sensitive to white space in your code, so when you generate them via JS, that whitespace doesn't exist unless you manually add it. The easiest way to see this is in your first example by putting all your divs on the same line with no spaces or carriage returns.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="1" class='box'></div><div class='box'></div><div class='box'></div>
```

Comment: And conversely, if you append a `document.createText("\n")` between each `box`, you’ll see the same result as in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks both of you, I haven't thought about it like that.